# Ordered Linked List errors

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I know all of the code isn't working but when I first run the program and the first string is read in from the text field the program errors out.The main function is passing the string to "Insert list function" in the implementation.
The program is suppose to insert a node every time that a string is read in from the text file. The program call also call the delete function which i know isn't working yet(that is why it is commented out). I am just trying to find the error that is created when the insert function is called. The main function has a while loop that creates a Node for every text entry and passes the node one by one to be sorted in ABC order.

Header file:

```
 #include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
string data;
Node * next;
};

class List
{
public:
List();
~List();
bool Insert(string);
bool Delete(string);
void Print();
bool Edit(string, string);
private:
 Node * head;
 Node * cur;
 Node * trailer;
 };
```

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;

List::List():head(NULL)
{} 
List::~List()
{}
bool List::Insert(string data)
{
Node* newNode = new Node;

if (newNode == NULL)
{
    cout << "Error: Memory Allocation Failed" << endl;
    return false;
}

newNode->data = data;
cur = head;
trailer = NULL;
if (head == NULL)
{
    //cout << "head is Null" << endl;
    head = newNode;
    cout << head -> data << endl;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    //return true;
}
while (newNode->data > cur->data && cur -> next != NULL)
{
    trailer = cur;
    cur = cur->next;

}

if (cur->next == NULL)
{
    cur->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return true;
}

else
{
    trailer->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = cur;
    return true;
   }

   }


bool List::Delete(string data)
{
/*Node *temp = head->next;
while (head != NULL)
{
    delete head;
    head = temp;
    temp = head->next;
}
return true;*/

}
bool List::Edit(string dataDelete, string dataInsert)
{
Delete(dataDelete);
Insert(dataInsert);
return true;
}
void List::Print()
{
for (Node * Count = head; Count != NULL; Count = Count->next)
{
    cout << Count->data << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Deepak is right, the problem is when you're inserting first element the `head` variable is `NULL` and `cur` is set to the value of `head`.

To fix it you can simply place

```
cur = head;
trailer = NULL;
```

after condition

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    //cout << "head is Null" << endl;
    head = newNode;
    cout << head -> data << endl;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    //return true;
}
```

Also there will be an error when you will try to insert element that should be placed in the beggining (value that is smaller than any other value in the list). It will happen when condition of the loop

```
trailer = NULL;
while (newNode->data > cur->data && cur -> next != NULL) { ... }
```

is false in the first call, so `trailer` will be `NULL`. To fix it you will need to check `trailer` variable, like this

```
if (trailer == NULL) {
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    return true;
}
```

As the result your code of `Insert` will look like

```
bool List::Insert(string data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: Memory Allocation Failed" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    newNode->data = data;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return true;
    }

    cur = head;
    trailer = NULL;
    while (newNode->data > cur->data && cur -> next != NULL)
    {
        trailer = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    if (trailer == NULL) {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return true;
    }

    if (cur->next == NULL)
    {
        cur->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        trailer->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = cur;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. One other question, the list I was sorting didn't come out completely sorted in abc order. the test list i was using is: pay bills, make dental appt, daily bible reading, get estimate on car repair, mail thank-you notes, take test. The list got sorted and outputted as : daily bible reading, get estimate on car, mail thank you notes, pay bills, make dental appt, take test.

Comment: @MatthewDanielSorrell There was an error in the code, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank so much! @NikolayKondratyev

Answer (score 0):

While inserting the first node you are getting error because of

```
while (newNode->data > cur->data && cur -> next != NULL)
```

At this moment **value in the cur is NULL** and you are trying to access **cur->data**.